# collection view horizontal scroll after set number of rows ? ios Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I currently have a collection view that connects to a server to get data and fill it up. How can I make it that once 3 rows (or x amount of rows) get full instead of adding another row to the collection view the collection view would become horizontally scrolling (essentially adding the new cells into new columns that you must scroll sideways to see)?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
if yourCollectionView.numberOfItemsInSection(0) >= x {
   let layout = yourCollectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout    
   layout.scrollDirection = .Horizontal
   yourCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
}
```

Or set the code inside of the `if` statement before you return the count in the `numberOfItemsInSection` method and refer to `x` in relation to what you return, for example:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let countToReturn = yourDataSource.count

    if countToReturn >= x {
        let layout = yourCollectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        layout.scrollDirection = .Horizontal
        yourCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
    }

    return countToReturn
}
```

Comment: after trying this the collection view cells just get pushed together and it doesnt become scrollabel

Comment: @user6520705 Updated the answer, use the method in the `numberOfItemsInSection` method, should work fine now.

Comment: so now everyhting looks good but it wont scroll horizontally and its just adding the 16th item into a new row

Comment: Post some of your code so I can better understand what you're doing